# OAuth2 error windows 8.1 GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

> Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols' from
>   assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

This error is thrown when attempting to call

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync.
```

I am developing under Windows 7 and my program works fine.  When trying to run under Windows 8.1, this error is thrown.

The difference I've found is under Windows 8.1, the System.Net.Primitives assembly version is 4.0.30319.33440 (8/9/2013) and under my Windows 7 working system the version is 4.0.30319.34209 (4/11/2014).

I've not found a way to update Windows 8.1 to this revision. I've tried to override loading the newer assembly through the manifest with no luck.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google.Apis packages direct different platforms. In order to run the project on Windows 8.1, you need to target Windows 8.1. That's why in our OAuth 2.0 page at at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth we included tutorials and code snippets for each environment. 
I specifically recommend you to use the code snippets at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#windows-81-applications.